# GWT cell table take value from a row

Tags: gwt

i have a problem

i have a GWT celltable with many information on each row, i need to extract a single information for each row;

can explain me how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a "SelectionModel" to your "CellTable" widget:

1. Choose a standard SelectionModel or write your own.
2. Add this SelectionModel to the cell widget using setSelectionModel(SelectionModel).
3. Create a SelectionChangeEvent.Handler implementing onSelectionChange.
4. Add this handler to the SelectionModel using addSelectionChangeHandler.

See [this sample](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#selection) for more information.

Comment: thx but i need to iterate all value of cell grid for find a specific value